# Can Java SE applications be clustered

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, corba

I have numerous Corba servers and some other java apps (not web). I wish to cluster them if possible. Can this be done?

Comment: What sort of clustering are you referring to?  Load balancing?  Data sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your applications are not web ones do not prevent them from being runnable on Java EE application servers. This would be the vest way to provide them any kind of clustering you wish, be it

- replication
- fault tolerance
- connection to distributed backend
- hot-swap upgrade

I would really suggest you give up on pure Java SE application to dive into the Java EE world.

Comment: Without knowing more about his situation, you can't make that judgement.

Comment: I'm making so-called "reasonable expectations" about his situation. Usually, when talking about J2SE application that connect to Corba servers, there are two possible use cases : client apps and associated server apps. Since client apps are a common case invloving classical load balancing and so on, I guess his problem is more a server-to-server one. But if my answer reveals to be incorrectly targetted, i won't hesitate at removing it, don't be worried about it.

Comment: thanks for all your quick and helpful responses. much appreciated. well, i would like to have the lot(load balancing, Data sharing, as well as clustering the instance of my software on other nodes) if possible. the applications i wish to be clustered and so on are :
4 X Socket listeners, 2 X Corba servers, and approx 6 X other database related java processes.

thanks in advance Riduidel and Skaffman its obvious ive asked the right people.

Comment: Then please consider marking your question as answered by checking the tick besinde the answer you think correct.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok, now that i know they can be clustered(thank you), how do go about doing this ? What tools would i require ? Currently im reading up on glassfish clustering but it seems it only clusters for high availability on web apps and ejbmodules. i dont see how i can cluster for HA on my corba servers and listeners. any ideas please ?

Comment: @ebe: Of course there are many scenarios where Java EE would be a terrible candidate, not to mention the size, learning curve, average lifespan and how restrictive its specifications can be. There are stable [Java SE alternatives](https://github.com/ThreaT/Java-SE-vs-Java-EE) to Java EE in every area and if not, then it's most likely a dud Java EE solution to begin with, that will eventually die. Why not get a [GitHub](http://www.github.com) account and contribute a pure Java SE clustering solution yourself? There's some really interesting mesh clustering ideas in the community right now